# Code always unfolding when I save in Visual Studio Code v. 1.28.2

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been thinking of switching to VS Code and have been trying it for a week, but some of its quirks are driving me away. Every time I save my file all the code unfolds and it scrolls back to the top. I have no extensions enabled. Anyone else having this?

Comment: Did this setting get changed: workbench.editor.restoreViewState: true,  True is the default.  Perhaps yours is false?

Comment: That setting is at the default.  I should add that this is happening when I save under a new name, not when I save under the current name.

Comment: I've uninstalled and reinstalled, and same behaviour.  Surely this can't be a feature?

Comment: When I reinstalled it was an upgrade to 1.29

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, anyway what seems to work (for me) is this:

- Open SETTINGS
- Search for FORMAT ON SAVE
- Turn  FORMAT ON SAVE on (ticked)
- Change FORMAT ON SAVE MODE to *modifications*